# converting double into NSNumber using [NSNumber numberWithDouble:]

Tags: iphone, nsnumber

there is a coordinate object with three variables latitude(NSNumber) ,longitude(NSNumber) and time(NSDate),for checking the program on my simulator,i gave the folowing code

```
[coordinate setLatitude:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:23.234223]];
[coordinate setLongitude:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:73.234323]];
```

however when i NSLog coordinate.latitude and coordinate.longitude,it diplays 0.00000

```
NSLog(@"cordlat :  %f",coordinate.latitude);
NSLog(@"cordlong :  %f",coordinate.longitude);
```

what can be the problem???

Comment: what type coordinate is?

Comment: coordinate is an object of class Coordinate which has three vars latitude,longitude and time,this object is to be used with coredata,so i defined the latitude & longitude as NSNumber type

Comment: question title and question description doesn't seem to match. :S

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't print an `NSNumber` with `%f`. You can do one of the following:

1. `NSLog(@"cordlat :  %@", coordinate.latitude);`
2. `NSLog(@"cordlat :  %f", coordinate.latitude.doubleValue);`